# no android studio gradle projects

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

There is no gradle project part in android studio, instead there is gradle. Can you help me?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for gradle tasklist?

Comment: I am looking for Debug signing certificate SHA-1

Comment: You'll need to build task list and then once make project again so that it'll show up on the gradle window

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix your issue of '*Task list not build during Gradle sync*', follow these steps:

1. Navigate to Android Studio settings/preferences *(ctrl + s/ cmd + ,)*
2. Go to **"Experimental"** -> uncheck the option **"Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync"**

See the screen below:

[image]

---

Now, click "make project" from the build option *.

* If that doesn't work then just restart Android Studio and after restarting, once gradle is synced, you'll be able to find task list.